# How can I hide/disable the "Send Feedback" link in SharePoint 2010 Managed Metadata picker?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am trying to hide the "Send Feedback" link in the modular window where you select managed metadata from the Term Store in SharePoint 2010. Although I haven't set an email address in the term store properties, the link is visible.

Answer (score 0):

Add javascript in your master page,

```
<script>
function pageLoad(sender, args) { 
  if (window.location.href.indexOf('termstoremanager.aspx') != -1) {
    //your code here to hide the send feedback
  }
}
</script>
```